# Project with shared lib and test application using that lib

Tags: linux, cmake

I've built a shared lib and a test application with CMake (2.8)

Now, after `make install`, I get a tree like this:

```
root/
  lib/
    mylib.so
  samples/
    test1
    test2
    ...
```

Now when I run my `test` app, it can't find the shared library file to run:

```
error while loading shared libraries: mylib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve this?

**EDIT**

Here is the relevant part of my CMakeLists.txt

For the `mylib`

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${LIB_SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(mylib ${VTK_LIBRARIES} ${OpenCV_LIBS})


install(TARGETS mylib DESTINATION lib)
install(FILES include/mylib.h DESTINATION include)
install(DIRECTORY models DESTINATION .)

add_subdirectory(samples)
```

For the executables folder:

```
file(GLOB APP_SOURCES RELATIVE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} *.cpp)

foreach( samplesourcefile ${APP_SOURCES} )

    string( REPLACE ".cpp" "" samplename ${samplesourcefile} )
    add_executable( ${samplename} ${samplesourcefile} )
    target_link_libraries( ${samplename} mylib )

    install(TARGETS ${samplename} DESTINATION samples)

endforeach( samplesourcefile )
```

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of you CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @hetepeperfan done :)

Comment: Well i'm not sure if im correct. But `target_link_libraries( ${samplename} mylib)` doesn't belong in the foreach loop. You only have to link once. So I would try to get that out of the loop, however I'm not sure whether that fixes your problem. The same goes for the install line as well i think.

Answer (score 0):

This may be caused because your library was installed in a non default directory in your Linux operating system.
File /etc/ld.so.conf contains the directories used by the dynamic loader for searching shared libs in Linux, see `ldconfig` manpage.
You can always check if all shared dependencies of a dynamic linked executable like your test application are found with command `ldd`.

So a solution to your missing library problem would be to install your library under a directory that your system uses as a search path for finding shared libraries.
A proper place to install development shared libraries in Linux distros is  `/usr/local/lib`; this is almost certainly included as a search path for shared libraries by default in all Linuxes. Likewise, development binaries like your test app would be better placed under `/usr/local/bin` (however having it elsewhere is not the cause of the missing lib problem).

For the record, here follows an excerpt about `/usr/local` as documented by [The Linux Documentation Project](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy.html#usr):

> [...] It copies the structure of '/usr'. These days, '/usr/local' is 
>   widely regarded as a good place in which to keep
>   self-compiled or third-party programs. The /usr/local hierarchy is for
>   use by the system administrator when installing software locally. It
>   needs to be safe from being overwritten when the system software is
>   updated. It may be used for programs and data that are shareable
>   amongst a group of hosts, but not found in /usr. Locally installed
>   software must be placed within /usr/local rather than /usr unless it
>   is being installed to replace or upgrade software in /usr.